# SQLAlchemy: Can't filter on hybrid property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this table:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "A"

    child_id = Column(
        Integer, 
        ForeignKey("child.id"), 
        default = -1, 
        nullable = False, 
        primary_key = True
    )
    composite_id = Column(
        Integer, 
        ForeignKey("composite.id"), 
        default = -1, 
        nullable = False, 
        primary_key = True
    )
    composite = relationship("composite", uselist=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def child_ids(self):
        if self.child_id != -1:
            res = (self.child_id, )
        else:
            res = []

            for c in self.composite.childs:
                res.append(c.id)

        return tuple(res)
```

and this `composite` table:

```
composite__child = Table(
    'composite__child', 
    Base.metadata,
    Column('composite_id', Integer, ForeignKey('composite.id')),
    Column('child_id', Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
)

composite_id_seq = Sequence('composite_id_seq')

class composite(Base):
    __tablename__ = "composite"

    id = Column(
        Integer, 
        server_default = composite_id_seq.next_value(), 
        nullable = False, 
        primary_key = True
    )
    name = Column(String(31), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    childs = relationship("child", secondary=composite__child)
```

The hybrid property works, but I can't filter on it:

```
>>> db_con.query(A).all()[1].child_ids
(615,)
>>> db_con.query(A).filter_by(child_ids=(615),).all()
[]
>>> db_con.query(A).filter(A.child_ids==(615),).all()
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach an [expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior) to the hybrid in order to do any filters. As an example (likely won't work directly since you didn't include the definition for `composite` or `child`):

```
class A(Base):
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def child_ids(self):
        ...

    @child_ids.expression
    def child_ids(cls):
        return case([((cls.child_id != -1), array([cls.child_id]))],
                    else_=func.array_agg(child.__table__.select().where(child.composite_id == cls.composite_id)))
```

Comment: I can retrieve what a need with this query: `child.__table__.select().alias("child_ids").join(composite__child).select().where(composite__child.c.composite_id == cls.composite_id)` but I can't convert it to an array of ids only.